# How to upload image in my project folder in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to upload an image to my project folder.
My project's structure is:

> ProjectName->WebContent->WEB-INF->resources

In my `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml` I added:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
    cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Now, in my controller, I uploaded the image using:

```
File path = new File("/home/bmshamsnahid/Tomcat Server/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/uploads");
if (!path.exists()) boolean status = path.mkdirs();
File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
item.write(uploadedFile);
```

Then the image can be found in  `/home/bmshamsnahid/Tomcat Server/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/uploads`, but if I use:

```
File path = new File("/resources");
```

Then it says it couldn't find that directory.

So, how do I upload an image to the `Project->WebContent->WEB-INF->resources` folder?

I don't use any dependency managers.

Comment: You don't. At runtime, there is no project folder. There isn't even a directory. Just your deployed .war file. Even if the war file is exploded, you don't want to put uploaded files there, because as soon as you'll deploy a new version of the app, you'll lose all the uploaded files. Uploaded files are data. They're not part of the project sources. Store them, as any other data, in the database or in an external directory.

Comment: This is not a good approach, if you do in this way, and deploy your war in another server or you need to restart for any reason, all the images were uploaded since the last war generation will be overwriten, would be better if you define a specific folder in your server and make reference from your controller.

Comment: I knew these limitations, i tried a lot to store image in my project folder like resources, but failed. So this is a plan B. Actually this is not going to the business, my semester project. Also I'm running out of time. So it's kind of a backup.